# CSS Responsive Image Animation (With Absolute Elements)

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try, I can't get this to be responsive.
I think the problem might be that it has few **absolute** elements inside it, but I'm not too sure about it?

I want to place this in the header so it will simply scale as the width of the page shrinks, but I can't get there...

HTML

```
<div class="conLogo">
<a id="cube" href="#">

<div class=weaver>
<img class="moveLittle" src="http://i.imgur.com/LyPWn45.png"></div>

<div class=ghost></div>

</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#conLogo {
width: 60%;
margin:0 auto;

}


#cube {
display: block;
margin: 30px auto;
height: 200px;  width: 1%;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}

#front {
position: absolute;  height: 200px;  width: 200px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform:  translateZ(100px);
backface-visibility: visible;
transform:  translateZ(100px);
}
#back {
position: absolute;  height: 200px;  width: 200px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform:  rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
backface-visibility: visible;
transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube {
-webkit-animation: upyourscache1377134648493 5s infinite linear;
animation: upyourscache1377134648493 5s infinite linear;

}
@-webkit-keyframes upyourscache1377134648493 {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) ;}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) ;}
}
@keyframes upyourscache1377134648493 {
0% { transform: rotateY(0) ;}
100% { transform: rotateY(360deg) ;}
}

.ghost{
background:#dfe;
margin:auto;
margin-top: -85px;

box-shadow:0 0 28px 9px #dfe;
color:#132;
width:20px; 
}

.moveLittle{
margin-left:-30px;

}


.ghost{
-webkit-animation:1.5s glow infinite alternate;
animation:1.5s glow infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow{
from {opacity:0.1;}
to {opacity:1.0;}
}
@keyframes glow{
from {opacity:0.1;}
to {opacity:1.0;}
}
```

The codepen link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPaBMp

Basically what I'm trying to get is this simple responsive effect: http://codepen.io/webcraftsman/pen/bwhtI

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: Your element `#cube` has a fixed width. How can it possible be responsive? Can you explain _exactly_ what you are trying to achieve? And also post your code in your question or it will most likely be closed.

Comment: ok, thanks for reply! this is my first post so bare with this noob!

Comment: Yes, but the cube without fixed width wouldn't rotate around its axis :/ do you maybe have any solution for that, width in percentages?

Comment: The question is, what HAVE you tried?

Comment: I've tried variations with max width, height and width auto, the simple things that works well with images or simple objects, but not when I have several a bit complicated elements.

As **uʍopǝpısdn** mentioned, my `#cube` has fixed with, but without it wouldn't rotate the right way :/